# Single geometry from PostGIS ST_Union()

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS PGSQL, is there a way to get the following to return a single geometry?

```
SELECT ST_Union(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom) FROM 
    table1 AS tbl1,
    table2 AS tbl2
    WHERE ST_DWithin(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom, 805)
    AND tbl2.date = '3/13/2014'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to group again after joining.  Your original query returns a combined table 1/table 2 geometry for each row - one for each row from both tables that matches the where clause.  You need to union all those geometries into one row.  One way to do it:

```
select st_union(geom) geom from
(SELECT distinct ST_Union(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom) geom FROM 
    table1 AS tbl1,
    table2 AS tbl2
    WHERE ST_DWithin(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom, 805)
    AND tbl2.date = '3/13/2014'
) foo;
```